# Simplify expression so nothing appears in denominator

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression that `FullSimplify` currently prefers to simplify with variables that have exponents appearing in the denominator if they have negative exponents, whereas I'd prefer that the expressions appear in the numerator, i.e. I'd prefer `1234 x^(-3)` whereas `FullSimplify` prefers `1234 / (x^3)`.

Any way to tell `FullSimplify` to prefer the first form?

Comment: If you evaluate `1234 x^(-3)`, the result has Fullform `Times[1234,Power[x,-3]]` which displays as `1234/x^3`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, I don't want the form of `1234/x^3`, I want `1234 x^(-3)`.

Comment: The point that @bills is making is that even if *Mathematica* represents the quantity as `x^(-3)` *internally*, it *displays* as `1/x^3`, so using something like `FullSimplify` won't work. If all you care about is getting something to *display* in that way, then going with something like eldo's answer might be what you want.

Comment: @Guillochon, just to hold it `1234 x^Defer@(-3)`

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
res = Inactivate[Sin[y] x^(-2), Power]
```

[image]

```
add = res + 10
```

[image]

```
Activate@add
```

[image]